# How to zip two lists with different lengths

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists that look like below:

```
my_list=[ 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 9]
another_list=['Yes','No']
```

The length of two lists is not same, but I want to concatenate them so that the final output can be as follows:

```
[[1, 'Yes'], [2, 'No'], [3, 'Yes'], [5, 'No'], [5, 'Yes'], [9, 'No']]
```

Can anyone help me on how I can achieve this, please?